# Rails controller, render command only works when copied?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render

I have encountered a very strange issue. I'm working my way through the sample blog application (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). In section 5.10, the article calls for modifying the article controller to add validation. The relevant section is below.

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
```

If I type this in and save the file, I get an error:

> undefined local variable or method `‘new’' for.....

However, if I copy and past the `new` from the article, it works! What the heck is THAT about?! I'm using TextEdit on a Mac, configured to save in UTF-8. Ruby version 2.2.2p95, Rails version 4.2.1. Everything else has worked fine.

When I was writing this question, I copied the `new` from my question into the controller, and it works. If I delete it, and type the exact same text, it throws the error!

I am baffled.

Comment: This is just a guess, maybe it's the type of ` you are using, can you try using double quote marks? I'm mostly talking about ` vs '.

Comment: Alternatively, use `:new` instead of quotes.

Comment: Yeah, your quotes are wrong. It says so in the error message. Instead of `‘` and `’`, you should be using `'`. I recommend using a different editor. One that has syntax highlighting. This would allow you to spot mistakes like this easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TextEdit is completely unsuitable for editing code, it'll constantly try and use “smart quotes” which are entirely inadequate for programming.

You can disable this in the preferences, but you're really fighting an uphill battle here, like how it defaults to a proportional font.

What you want is something that doesn't mangle your text as you write by presuming it to be human language. [TextMate](https://macromates.com/), [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) and [Atom](https://atom.io/) are all good choices.

It's also worth noting that [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) is also an option, though it's usually overkill for Ruby code.

Comment: And, FWIW, TextMate and Atom are completely free ... so, really, no good reason not to use them over TextEdit :).

Comment: Thank you SO much! I was able to fix the problem immediately.